# Adjust screen size on different browsers

Tags: html

**Facts:**

1. My website was created in 1024 x 768 pixels resolution.
2. It's OK to view my site in the same screen resolution.

**My Problem:**

1. It is not Okay to view my site in a 800 x 600 resolution having screen.

is there any perfect or best way to solve this issue ? Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be the way on how you coded it. Here are some possible scenarios:

1.) Your length and width position could be in absolute or fixed. E.g.

`#container
position: absolute/*of fixed*/;`

2.) The type of metric used for measurement are pixels rather than percentages (%). There is a big difference between these two:

`#container
Height: 100px;`

and

`#container
Height: 20%;`

3.)You might be using deprecated features from the old html versions or your browser does not support new features. Try adding [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/). This add-on will support your website into old browsers

It is best if you use [CSS3 Media Queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) to optimize your website to your desired sizes. This can also be used to support your website into mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use absolute sizes if you don't user to have different experiences based on their resolutions.  Use relative sizes on your components.

Liquid design mimiks what I suggest: http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/flexible-liquid-design.htm & http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

... and there's also Elastic design: http://alistapart.com/article/elastic

Comment: @user3400389 Exactly.

Comment: but i can't use 100% everywhere now. :/

Comment: @user3400389 Check my edit, I think that's what you're looking for.  And it doesn't have to be 100%, use % based on what that component should take up.  Anyways... read those articles - lots of good insight.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), using which you can modify the layout of your sites based on screen resolutions / available width.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to you set your `<body>` style like this way,

```
body {
    font-size: 13px;                                   /* As per your style */
    font-weight: normal;                               /* As per your style */
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', Arial, Verdana, Tahoma; /* As per your style */
    text-align: left;
    background: #FFF;   
    overflow:auto;
    background:scroll;
    width:1007px;
    max-width:1007px;
    min-width:1007px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This is best fit to all screen size resolution. if you use 800x600 size its come scroll-bar both side, if lasge size 1366x768 show in middle both size margin auto.

[Demo site](http://way2tutorial.com/html/tag/index.php) you check this is best fit website. This page is look like newspaper type page.

You can check <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (Increase), <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (Decrease) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (Normal Size).

Comment: Why not use Firefox Responsive Design? ctrl + shift + m